# WebAPI 2.2 on .Net core with IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation throws NullreferenceException

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, identityserver3, owin-middleware

I'm having a hard time getting this to work. Currently I already have got an IdentityServer4, an Angular2SPA and a WebAPI 2.2 for ODATA running. All services are running in individual projects on asp.net core.

- IdentityServer4
- Angular2SPA
- WebAPI2.2 .core targeting .Net462

The WebAPI runs fine as long as i dont try to connect it to the IdentityServer. 
I have verified that my setup, beside the WebAPI, works correctly.
I have also tested the WebAPI connection configuration with the IdentityServer3.Samples on Github by connecting their WebAPISample with my IdentityServer.

## WebAPI

### Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddAuthorization();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseOwinApp(owinApp =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                owinApp.UseErrorPage(new ErrorPageOptions()
                {
                    ShowCookies = true,
                    ShowEnvironment = true,
                    ShowExceptionDetails = true,
                    ShowHeaders = true,
                    ShowQuery = true,
                    ShowSourceCode = true
                });
            }

            owinApp.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            owinApp.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            owinApp.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://authentication.bl.at:5000",
                RequiredScopes = new[] { "bl.API" },
                //ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
                //DelayLoadMetadata = true,

                //// client credentials for the introspection endpoint
                ClientId = "bl.API",
                ClientSecret = "secret"
            });


            WebAPIConfig.Register(config);


            ODataModelBuilder odataMetadataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            odataMetadataBuilder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: "odata",
                model: odataMetadataBuilder.GetEdmModel());
            owinApp.UseWebApi(config);
        });
    }
}
```

### OwinExtensions.cs

```
public static class OwinExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseOwinApp(this IApplicationBuilder aspNetCoreApp, Action<IAppBuilder> configuration)
    {
        return aspNetCoreApp.UseOwin(setup => setup(next =>
        {
            AppBuilder owinAppBuilder = new AppBuilder();

            IApplicationLifetime aspNetCoreLifetime = (IApplicationLifetime)aspNetCoreApp.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IApplicationLifetime));

            AppProperties owinAppProperties = new AppProperties(owinAppBuilder.Properties);

            owinAppProperties.OnAppDisposing = aspNetCoreLifetime?.ApplicationStopping ?? CancellationToken.None;

            owinAppProperties.DefaultApp = next;

            configuration(owinAppBuilder);

            return owinAppBuilder.Build<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>>();
        }));
    }
}
```

### WebAPIConfig.cs

```
public class WebAPIConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

### Exceptions

The WebAPI works as expected as long as oauth is disabled, when it's enabled it throws the following exception on startup:

```
Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.DiscoveryDocumentIssuerSecurityTokenProvider..ctor(String discoveryEndpoint, IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   bei Owin.IdentityServerBearerTokenValidationAppBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass9.<ConfigureLocalValidation>b__8()
   bei System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   bei System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   bei Owin.IdentityServerBearerTokenValidationAppBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(IAppBuilder app, IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions options)
   bei WebAPI.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Configure>b__0(IAppBuilder owinApp) in C:\Users\User\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\src\WebAPI\Startup.cs:Zeile 78.
   bei WebAPI.Config.OwinExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<UseOwinApp>b__1(Func`2 next) in C:\Users\User\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\src\WebAPI\Config\OwinExtensions.cs:Zeile 29.
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.OwinExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<UseOwin>b__1(RequestDelegate next1)
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   bei WebAPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\src\WebAPI\Program.cs:Zeile 21.
```

I have also tried enabling delayLoadMetadata but this throws the following exception:

```
Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
   bei IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerBearerTokenValidationMiddleware..ctor(Func`2 next, IAppBuilder app, IdentityServerOAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   bei lambda_method(Closure , Func`2 , IAppBuilder , IdentityServerOAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions , ILoggerFactory )
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   bei System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   bei Microsoft.Owin.Builder.AppBuilder.BuildInternal(Type signature)
   bei Microsoft.Owin.Builder.AppBuilderExtensions.Build[TApp](IAppBuilder builder)
   bei WebAPI.Config.OwinExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<UseOwinApp>b__1(Func`2 next) in C:\Users\User\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\src\WebAPI\Config\OwinExtensions.cs:Zeile 31.
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.OwinExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<UseOwin>b__1(RequestDelegate next1)
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   bei WebAPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\src\WebAPI\Program.cs:Zeile 21.
```

I think this issue might be related to .Core/Owin dependency injection of ILoggerFactory. Might be a lifespan issue between these two?

Comment: Is the well known endpoint under https://authentication.bl.at:5000 working?   Check by open it in browser

Comment: Yes, i have verified that the authentication server works correctly. I can login with my ng2-Frontend and I am receiving an accesstoken. The Webapi throws the error on startup, I dont think it is a configuration issue, I believe it has something to do with mixing the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions that you got before and after enabled `DelayLoadMetadata` are different, one is from constructor of `DiscoveryDocumentIssuerSecurityTokenProvider` while another is from constructor of `IdentityServerBearerTokenValidationMiddleware`

If you have a look at the implementation of [UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/blob/a688863045e89ea5dfea0041e6c6ebb33bda99f5/source/AccessTokenValidation/IdentityServerBearerTokenValidationAppBuilderExtensions.cs), you would see both modules depend on `loggerFactory` which gets from `IApplicationBuilder` by this line

```
        var loggerFactory = app.GetLoggerFactory();
```

I am not a .net core expert, but the way how you use `UseOwin` extension method looks a bit strange to me, where you have a new instance of `AppBuilder` inside your owin pipeline instead of using the existing one - `aspNetCoreApp`, my guess is there is no logger factory registered with the new instance of `AppBuilder`, therefore when it is needed in modules in IdentityServer3, it blows up with `object is null` exception.

You can easily find out by setting a breakpoint before call into  `IdentityServerBearerTokenValidationMiddleware` and manualy executes `owinAppBuilder.GetLoggerFactory()` in `Immediate` debug window to see if it returns anything

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue, and i also tried it with the
*DelayLoadMetadata = true* option without any success.

To solve this problem i needed to set a default logger with app.SetLoggerFactory, before you call
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(GetOptions());
To do this you might need to ad

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Logging;
```

to your using’s and maybe add the assembly reference, this will add the *SetLoggerFactory* method to the app object. (it´s an extension).
In my case i´ve done it just with the default logger like this:

```
app.SetLoggerFactory(Microsoft.Owin.Logging.LoggerFactory.Default);
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
    //some stuff
    });
);
```